# Ember 2.3 | Record is updated on save(), but Ember still says that it failed on dev ENV

Tags: ember.js

Given the following code snippets, Ember.js keeps hitting the following alert everytime I press the update button on Edit.hbs while in development mode:

> alert('failed to update user!')

However, what makes this issue different is that the record is persisted on the server side with a `200 (M'kay)` reply, and when I am in production mode with my live website, Ember.js confirms that the user has been updated with the other alert()... Any thoughts on what could be the source of this issue?

I have seen quite a few examples around, but I am suspecting that most of them are no longer valid for the 2.0 ember versions...

**Router**

```
this.route('user', { path:'user/:user_id' }, function() {
    this.route('edit');
});
```

**Edit Controller**

```
// Removed extra code that controls warning messages to model.user
// and comparison to model.users
update: function(user) {
    // Extra Code that checks current_password and others omitted.
    user.save().then(function() {
        alert('User Updated!');
        // transitionToRoute errors with undefined...
        this.controller.transitionToRoute('user', user);    
    }, function() {
        alert('failed to update user!');
    });
}
```

**Edit Route**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend ({
    model: function() {
        return Ember.Object.create ({
            user: this.modelFor('user'),
            users: this.store.findAll('user')
        });
    }
});
```

**Edit Template (Button Only)**

```
<button class="button_type1" {{action "update" model.user}}>Update User</button>
```

[Live Website](http://fakktion.herokuapp.com/user/2/edit)
This will take you directly to User #2 edit page. At the moment you will have unrestricted access to the website as this will make it easier for bug hunting... Changing password is not working, but the other attributes should persist as discussed previously.
[Source Code](https://github.com/Deovandski/fakktion)

### EDIT #1

`this.transitionToRoute('user', user);` is now working as expected based on Deewendra's answer.

```
user.save().then(() => {
    alert('User Updated!');
    this.transitionToRoute('user', user);
}).catch(() => {
    alert('User Not Updated!');
});
```

### EDIT #2

By appending reason to the catch statement, I was able to narrow down the second issue that I was having:

```
user.save().then(() => {
    // Not reaching
}).catch((reason) => {
    console.log(reason); //Assertion Failed: normalizeResponse must return a valid JSON API document: * Top level of a JSON API document must be an object.
});
```

The server terminal kept telling me 200 OK, but the actual response was badly formatted on the Rails side. If you encounter a similar problem, then make the following changes on your Rails controller:

```
// Outputs Bad JSON
render json: user.update(user_params)

// Output proper JSON
user.update(user_params)
render json: user
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue lies in the controller code. When you do user.save(), it returns a promise and for any function you call on it, the context will be the promise itself so in your then block 'this' points to the promise object and not the router instance so it cannot resolve this.controller and hence although it saves your model, the control goes to the catch/fail block. To solve this you can do :

1) bind context to the 'then' function

```
update: function(user) {
    // Extra Code that checks current_password and others omitted.
    user.save().then(function() {
        alert('User Updated!');
        // transitionToRoute errors with undefined...
        this.controller.transitionToRoute('user', user); 
        //OR this.transitionTo('user', user);   
    }.bind(this), function() {
        alert('failed to update user!');
    });
}
```

2) store router instance in a variable outside 'then' so its accessible within the then block

```
update: function(user) {
    // Extra Code that checks current_password and others omitted.
    var context = this;
    user.save().then(function() {
        alert('User Updated!');
        // transitionToRoute errors with undefined...
        context.controller.transitionToRoute('user', user);    
    }, function() {
        alert('failed to update user!');
    });
}
```

3) Or use ES6 arrow function which will bind this context automagically. I have not tried these before, but it should work.

```
    user.save().then(()=> {
        alert('User Updated!');
        this.controller.transitionToRoute('user', user);    
    }, () => {
        alert('failed to update user!');
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You could also chain `.catch()` instead of passing a function. `user.save().then(() => {}).catch(() => {});`

Comment: `.catch()`did the trick. However, would you know the possible root cause for the save() function to always trigger the failed alert event even though the server replied with **200 OK**?

Comment: This will help http://emberjs.com/api/classes/RSVP.Promise.html#toc_chaining. Again your save() was not the issue, it worked perfectly fine, once your save promise resolved it executes the "success handler" method which was causing js error to be thrown because it was unable to resolve this.controller and so since your success handler threw an exception, the control is passed to the "rejection handler". Control to rejection handler is passed if either your save request fails or something in the "success handler" throws error, and it your case it was the later.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The link you provided allowed me to narrow the issue down to `Assertion Failed: normalizeResponse must return a valid JSON API document: * Top level of a JSON API document must be an object.` I will post a **edit #2** explaining the issue.