# Emberjs - how to reset a field on a component after saving?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-components

I have an embedded object called Comment, inside a Game. Each game can have many Comments.

When a user (called a Parent) views the game page, they can leave a comment.

The problem I have is that I cannot seem to reset the body of the comment field back to empty after the comment is saved.

This is the component:

```
MyApp.AddCommentComponent = Ember.Component.extend({

  body: '',
  actions: {
    addComment: function() {

      var comment, failure, success;
      if (!!this.get('body').trim()) {
        comment = this.store.createRecord('comment', {
          body: this.get('body'),
          game: this.get('game'),
          parent_id: this.get('parent_id'),
          parent_name: this.get('parent_name')
        });

        success = (function() {
          this.set('body', '');
        });
        failure = (function() {
          return console.log("Failed to save comment");
        });
        return comment.save().then(success, failure);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The error is on the 'this.set' line - **this.set is not a function**

All the examples I find are about doing this in a controller or by creating a new record upon route change (but the route is not changing in my example, since it is just adding another embedded object to the existing page).

Comment: Its solution provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534260/ember-2-3-record-is-updated-on-save-but-ember-still-says-that-it-failed-on/35537284#35537284 will work for you too. But briefly let me throw in other options:
(1) success = function() {
          this.set('body', '');
        }.bind(this);
(2) success = ()=> {
          this.set('body', '');
        };
(3) return comment.save().then(()=>{ this.set('body', ''); }).catch(()=>{ //log err; });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using

```
this.set('body', '');
```

in success, but the scope of this here is changed, you need to keep the controller scope and set the body to empty string like

```
MyApp.AddCommentComponent = Ember.Component.extend({

  body: '',
  actions: {
    addComment: function() {
      var that = this;
      var comment, failure, success;
      if (!!this.get('body').trim()) {
        comment = this.store.createRecord('comment', {
          body: this.get('body'),
          game: this.get('game'),
          parent_id: this.get('parent_id'),
          parent_name: this.get('parent_name')
        });

        success = (function() {
          that.set('body', '');
        });
        failure = (function() {
          return console.log("Failed to save comment");
        });
        return comment.save().then(success, failure);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it! And I understand why, so thank you for explaining about the scope issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you introduce a `function`, you must remember that the value for `this` is not (necessarily) the same as the enclosing scope's value for `this`.  Save the reference to the `Component` to use in a closure, like this:

```
MyApp.AddCommentComponent = Ember.Component.extend({

  body: '',
  actions: {
    addComment: function() {

      var comment, failure, success;
      var self= this;

      if (!!this.get('body').trim()) {
        comment = this.store.createRecord('comment', {
          body: this.get('body'),
          game: this.get('game'),
          parent_id: this.get('parent_id'),
          parent_name: this.get('parent_name')
        });

        success = (function() {
          self.set('body', '');
        });
        failure = (function() {
          return console.log("Failed to save comment");
        });
        return comment.save().then(success, failure);
      }
    }
  }
});
```